# Why can I use reflection to call private methods of an external class?

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

I can use reflection to access and call private methods of a class outside of my library. Is this a bug or desired behaviour? If it's desired, how can I make it impossible for external code to access private members/methods?

```dart
library left;

class Thing {
  void _priv(String s) {
    print(s);
  }
}

library right;

void main() {
  var t = new Thing();
  var mirror = reflect(t);

  mirror.type.declarations.values
  .where( (d) => d.isPrivate && d is MethodMirror )
  .forEach( (d) {
    print(d.simpleName == #_priv); // prints false
    mirror.getField(d.simpleName).reflectee("Hello World"); // prints Hello World
  });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This privacy is not a security feature, is's only to communicate to users of your API that such a method is intended for internal usage only. Access using mirrors can't be prevented.

Disallowing it in mirrors wouldn't prevent access because the VM and dart2js just mangle or prefix private method names to prevent name collisions with public methods. These names can be predicted or found using brute force and then be called.

Comment: Correct. The security units in Dart are isolates, not libraries. One isolate cannot affect code in another isolate without cooperation. Inside an isolate, library privacy is only a convenience to allow you to write names that won't be accidentally shadowed by other libraries. Mirrors allow access to the entire isolate.

Answer (score 0):

Calling private methods are mostly useful in writing the DSL(Domain Specific Language)s.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more. I don't understand your answer.